# How to customize Visual Studio Solution Explorer right click menu options?

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using Visual Studio since further back then I can remember. Over the years, each new release saw a trend of an ever-growing number of options added to the right-click context menu in the Solution Explorer. 99% of the time I use only 5% of these context menu options. I would like to know if it is possible to remove items from the context menu?

For example:

Open Visual Studio->Create a Solution->Add a project to it->Find the project in the Solution Explorer->Right click on the project->Observe a large number of right-click-menu options.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019 CE with a C# build environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete items from the project context menu going to Tools - Customize - Commands - Context menu - Project and Solution Context Menus | Project:

[image]

Comment: That worked great. I'd just like to point out that the preview won't read exactly the same as what you actually see when you right click - but they both represent the same items.