# In Visual Studio 2019 - How do I add a 'New Textfile Item' shortcut into the solution explorer context menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am wanting to add a new context menu item into visual studio's solution explorer context menu. As seen in the image below;
[image: Solution Explorer context menu]

I want this context menu to create a new textfile. (Basically the same as Add -> New Item but configured as a new textfile)....

I see that you can add items to the context menu as seen in this post here: [How to customize Visual Studio Solution Explorer right click menu options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070704/how-to-customize-visual-studio-solution-explorer-right-click-menu-options)
But I don't see a clear way to make it add a new textfile, only more basic options.

Alternatively, is there a shortcut I can use? I have tried the File-> New File -> TextFile option. But that will not add it to the solution's folder.